# how do you call arbitrary object methods from a standalone function python

Tags: python, django

I want to call methods of different classes that are named the same, the purpose to be able to call save() or delete() on different django models (of course all django models have the same methods). I tried:

```
class X(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def double(self):
        self.value = self.value * 2

    def triple(self):
        self.value = self.value * 3


def testcallback(obj, callback):
    return obj.callback
```

and calling it any way doesn't work

```
In [26]: y = testcallback(x, triple)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-09fc8db1d48b> in <module>()
----> 1 y = testcallback(x, triple)

NameError: name 'triple' is not defined

In [31]: y = testcallback(x, triple())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-5a7a2dd91850> in <module>()
----> 1 y = testcallback(x, triple())

NameError: name 'triple' is not defined
```

I keep doing the same check for different related models, then either saving or deleting based on which form they came in from. How do I send arbitrary object and method names into a function, then call the method chosen on the object chosen in python? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can call the methods using getattr:

```
def testcallback(obj, callback):
    getattr(obj, callback)()
```

Comment: where'd the params come from

Comment: ok so if I want params, maybe take em as a third arg in the main func

Comment: Yes, add them to the function and then to getattr

Comment: And don't forget that when calling `testcallback`, the callback parameter should be a string.